# Is there a list of normalized character decomposition ( to 足, 龰 to 止, etc.)?

Tags: characters, character-components

I tried .txt of each files in CHISE IDS (https://www.chise.org/ids/) but it seems that most of the components are not normalized. Is there any work that has normalized the characters in IDS?

Comment: what do you mean by normalized? for example the component version of 火 could be 灬 or 火-- with both being equally common.  Also many components are made up of other components, while still being components themselves.  If you explain what you mean by normalized we can better help with what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the correct location for the up-to-date IDS, that is, at https://babelstone.co.uk/CJK/IDS.TXT, the following correspondences are listed:

> The following special radical forms are used:
>
> - 牜 for 牛 (ox) on the left
> - for dotless 玉 (jade) on the left
> - for 竹 (bamboo) on top (unless actually written as 竹)
> - 艹 for 艸 (grass) on top (unless actually written as 艸); joined (3 strokes) and broken (4 strokes) forms are not distinguished
> - 月 for 肉 (meat) on the left if written the same as 月 (moon); ⺼ is used only when it is distinguished from 月, but currently almost only
>   in the URO (completing ⺼/月 distinction is on the TO DO list)
> - 糹 for three-dotted 糸 (silk) on the left (enables automatic conversion to/from corresponding lhs-only simplified component 纟)
> - 訁 for 言 (speech) on the left (enables automatic conversion to/from corresponding lhs-only simplified component 讠)
> - 釒 for 金 (gold) on the left (enables automatic conversion to/from corresponding lhs-only simplified component 钅)
> - 飠 for 食 (food) on the left (unless written with the final dot) (enables automatic conversion to/from corresponding lhs-only
>   simplified component 饣)
>
> On the other hand, 孑 and ⺶ on the left are normalized to 子 and 羊
> respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I am looking for.